# Numbers: checking if cell with specific text exists

Tags: macos, numbers, iwork

### Prerequisites

I have some tables with cells like so:

[image]

Also, I have some more tables like so:

[image]

---

### Objective

Note the `YES` and `NO`. in the `Included` column in the `Example Requirements` table.

- You will note that for `JAE 101` in the `Example Requirements`, a `YES` is to the right, because I have included it in the `Example Semester` table.
- Conversely, there is a `NO` to the right of `OME 321` because there is no such ID in the `Example Semester`.
- Also, there is `YAE 555` which has nothing to do with the `Example Requirements` table.

---

### Problem

Unfortunately, the described scenario was a mockup; the `YES` and `NO` were placed manually by myself.

**What formula do I put in the `Included` column of the `Example Requirements` table to reproduce such scenario?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formula works where A3 is the cell which contains the search string and "Example Semester::A3:A4" is the range to search.

```
IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A3,Example Semester::A3:A4,0),FALSE),"YES","NO")
```

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks! Before I give you a green check-mark, I have one more requirement: How do I have multiple cells from different tables to check? i.e. How do I make "Example Semester:: $A$2:$A$3" into something like "Semester 1:: $A$2:$A$3" AND "Semester 2:: $A$2:$A$3"?

Comment: @SirJony Non-contiguous cell ranges are not possible in Numbers.

Comment: Seriously!? Do you happen to know if Excel on Mac supports it?

Comment: @SirJony You can use a comma-delimited list of ranges enclosed in {} with Excel's indirect function.

Comment: OK, thanks for the additional information. Apple really need to up the ante on their software. :)